# Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client in express app due to wrapper

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

i'm creating some routes for a project and i use an asyncWrapper to handle errors

```
function asyncWrapper(fn) {
    return (req, res, next) => {
        fn(req, res, next).catch(next);
    }
}

export default asyncWrapper;
```

and until now nothing bad was happening.

today i created the reviews model and tried to implement this route

```
app.post('/campgrounds/:id/reviews', (req, res) => {
    res.send(req.body);
});
```

but i forgot it was not async so i added it:

```
app.post(
    '/campgrounds/:id/reviews',
    asyncWrapper((req, res) => {
        res.send(req.body);
    }),
);
```

and i get this error even though the clientside has nothing wrong:

```
Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client
    at ServerResponse.setHeader (node:_http_outgoing:652:11)
    at ServerResponse.header (C:\Users\albip\Desktop\programmazione\udemy\YelpCampFake\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:794:10)
    at ServerResponse.send (C:\Users\albip\Desktop\programmazione\udemy\YelpCampFake\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:174:12)
    at done (C:\Users\albip\Desktop\programmazione\udemy\YelpCampFake\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:1035:10)
    at C:\Users\albip\Desktop\programmazione\udemy\YelpCampFake\node_modules\ejs-mate\lib\index.js:356:7
    at tryHandleCache (C:\Users\albip\Desktop\programmazione\udemy\YelpCampFake\node_modules\ejs\lib\ejs.js:280:5)
    at exports.renderFile (C:\Users\albip\Desktop\programmazione\udemy\YelpCampFake\node_modules\ejs\lib\ejs.js:491:10)
    at renderFile (C:\Users\albip\Desktop\programmazione\udemy\YelpCampFake\node_modules\ejs-mate\lib\index.js:298:7)
    at C:\Users\albip\Desktop\programmazione\udemy\YelpCampFake\node_modules\ejs-mate\lib\index.js:353:7
    at tryHandleCache (C:\Users\albip\Desktop\programmazione\udemy\YelpCampFake\node_modules\ejs\lib\ejs.js:280:5)
```

interestingly when i add the wrapper and set the function as async the error doesn't pop up.
i'm confused about why does this happen. thanks